# Is there a more succinct CSS selector expression for this Stack Overflow improvement?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I created [this user style](http://userstyles.org/styles/23207) to make my Stack Overflow use much more pleasant. As the screenshots there illustrate, my sidebar contains only the "Ignored Tags" header and input box. I don't care about all of the unanswered tags, nor about all of the tags I've already ignored. Here is the CSS:

```css
#sidebar > * { display: none }
#sidebar > :nth-child(5) { display: inherit }
#sidebar > :nth-child(5) > * { display: none }
#sidebar > :nth-child(5) > :nth-child(4) { display: inherit }
#sidebar > :nth-child(5) > :nth-child(6) { display: inherit }
```

This ultimately means "Hide everything except children 4 and 6 of child 5 of the sidebar." It works beautifully, but looks ridiculous. Do you care to golf, and improve my selector-fu?

Comment: Meta comment: SO's syntax highlighting needs to speak CSS.

Comment: First, I think you should correct that 5 with a 2. I see an Ad instead of the ignore tags box!

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. It must be an interaction with AdBlock on my end!

Comment: Why the downvotes? The question isn't useful?

Comment: @Jonathan My guess is that the downvotes were because this looks like a code golf/code review question—both of which have their own dedicated Stack Exchange sites. Personally, I think it's a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you consider this less ridiculous, but here's how I did it with only two rules:

```css
#sidebar > :not(:nth-child(5)) { display: none }
#sidebar ul > :not(:nth-child(4)):not(:nth-child(6)) { display: none }
```

1. Hide every sidebar child except the 5th one.
2. Inside all of the sidebar's lists, hide every child except the 4th and 6th.

Depending on the actual markup of the sidebar, you might have to replace the `ul` in rule two with something else.

Comment: A great answer. Educational, and cleeeean. (I replaced "ul" with "div" to fit the situation). Thanks.